# All Routes Suddenly Resulting in 404 Page After Dev Server Restart NextJS 13 App Router

Tags: reactjs, vercel, next.js13, app-router

I noticed I had a hydration error so I killed the local dev sever and restarted it. After the restart, all my routes that were previously working just fine began giving me the generic NextJS 404 page. The last thing I did before this error was change the the site title and description in the root layout.
[my next.config file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oKtMW.png)

I tried restarting the server multiple times, deleting the .next directory, and trying different solutions in next.config. So far nothing has solved the problem.

Comment: Hi. It's hard to help you sort this out without some code examples. Can you provide a minimal repro, or at least some code snippets related to your work and the changes you made?

Comment: @DewaunAyers I narrowed down the issue to have something to do with the shadcn package. I just spun up a new nextjs project to set it up like the project giving me the issues. It was after installing shadcn that I ran into the same exact issue. It looks like there is a github issue for this https://github.com/shadcn-ui/ui/issues/755. I'm going to try out some of the solutions there, thanks!

Comment: So the problem was that I was using the src directory and when I added shadcn it created a new app directory with globals.css at the project root. In case anyone else runs into this problem, I solved it by deleting the /app directory that shadcn created and updating the path to globals.css in components.json from app/globals.css to src/app/globals.css.

Comment: Thank you so much. I wouldn't have figured it out, that the error was coming due to shadcn. Worked absolutely!!